# Export field list to excel or csv

Tags: arcpy, csv, excel

I've got the below script and found very useful. But I need the list of fields to be exported to excel or csv.

```
import arcpy

#Set workspace environment to geodatabase
arcpy.env.workspace = "e:/temp/ramac.gdb"

#Get list of feature classes in geodatabase
FCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

#Loop through feature classes in list
for FC in FCs:

    #List fields in feature class
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(FC)

    #Loop through fields
    for field in fields:

            #Print feature class, field, domain name
            print FC, field.name, field.type, field.length
```

Comment: I would use an InsertCursor to write your values to a table and then export that table to Excel.

Comment: iam new to arcpy and practising now. can you please add...

Comment: The best way to learn to write an InsertCursor is when you need one. Use CreateTable then AddFields prior to opening it. We do not offer a code on request service but if you make a reasonable attempt and then get stuck a potential answerer will usually help on that bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using the CSV module, I find it an extremely useful module to know, especially with any kind of reporting that needs to be done.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

I have made up this code, I don't have arcpy on my computer at home, so you will need to check if it works

```
import csv
import arcpy

csvLocation = r'/desktop/test.csv'
arcpy.env.workspace = r"e:/temp/ramac.gdb"

#write header
with open(csvLocation,'wb') as openCSV:
    a = csv.writer(openCSV)
    message = [['FC','NAME', 'TYPE', 'LENGTH']]
    a.writerows(message)

    #Get list of feature classes in geodatabase
    FCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()    

    #Loop through feature classes in list
    for FC in FCs:
        #List fields in feature class
        fields = arcpy.ListFields(FC)

        #Loop through fields and write to csv
        for field in fields:

            message = [[FC, field.name, field.type, field.length]]
            a.writerows(message)
```